# web2py validating db model for group menbers

Tags: python, web2py

I am using web2py, and am trying to build a field for auth_user, that should be validated to be a member of a certain group. So, in the models/db.py I have added a field that tells who is the manager of the user:

```
auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user']=[Field('manager', 'reference auth_user')]
```

Then I have set up to `db.auth_user`, `db.auth_group` and `db.auth_membership` to contain users that belong to group 'managers'

And what I would like now to achieve is to validate user input so, that the 'manager' field of the `auth_user` could contain only users from the group 'managers'. I have gone through quite a few variations, following is maybe closest to making sense in theory in my mind:

```
group_id = auth.id_group('managers') 
all_users_in_group = db(db.auth_membership.group_id==group_id)._select(db.auth_membership.user_id)
db.auth_user.auditor.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, db(~db.auth_user.id.belongs(all_users_in_group)).select(db.auth_user.id))
```

But even that is failing with

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>('Table' object has no attribute 'managers')
```

A perfect solution to my problem would show in the drop down menu not `auth_user.id`, but `auth_user.first_name` concatenated with `auth_user.last_name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done it correctly in your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40790384/4065350), but you can improve it.

The first argument of the validator can be a database connection or a DAL Set. So you can pass
directly a db query as first argument, like this

```
query = db((db.auth_membership.group_id == auth.id_group('managers')) &
           (db.auth_membership.user_id == db.auth_user.id))
db.auth_user.auditor.requires = IS_IN_DB(query, db.auth_user.id, '%(first_name)s %(last_name)s')
```

You can also write query like below:

```
query = db((db.auth_group.role == 'managers') &
           (db.auth_membership.group_id == db.auth_group.id) &
           (db.auth_membership.user_id == db.auth_user.id))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used similar code to the following and confirm that is works with web2py  2.17.2-stable+timestamp.2018.10.06.18.54.02 (Running on nginx/1.14.0, Python 3.6.7).The previous answer will not work for this version.

```
group_id = auth.id_group('managers')
user_rows = db(db.auth_membership.group_id == group_id)._select(db.auth_membership.user_id)
query = db(db.auth_user.id.belongs(user_rows))
db.auth_user.auditor.requires = IS_IN_DB(query, db.auth_user.id, '%(first_name)s %(last_name)s'
```

Comment: @DebanjanB thank you, I added more explanatory comment on why I posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to solve this, but I would definitely not call this elegant. Would there be more idiomatic way to do this in web2py? Following is what I added to models/db.py

```
group_id = auth.id_group('managers')
rows=db(db.auth_membership.group_id==group_id).select(db.auth_membership.user_id)
rset=set()
for r in rows:
    rset.add(int((r.user_id)))

db.auth_user.auditor.requires = IS_IN_DB(db(db.auth_user.id.belongs(rset)), db.auth_user.id, '%(first_name)s %(last_name)s')
```